# Выделение памяти под константное свойство в классе

Tags: c#, ооп

Имеется класс:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass() { }

    public const int SomeUsefulValue = 42;
}
```

Создавая несколько (2 и более) экземпляров этого класса, память под константную переменную выделится один раз и переменная будет одна для каждого экземпляра? Или же для каждого экземпляра будет уникальная константная переменная?

Comment: констант нет. Все упоминания будут заменены непосредственным значением при компиляции

Comment: если смотреть с точки зрения языка, поведение `const` аналогично поведению `static readonly`, поэтому константа одна на класс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Констант нет.

Все упоминания константы будут заменены непосредственным значением при компиляции. Именно поэтому константы можно инициализировать только значениями, известными во время компиляции.

если смотреть с точки зрения языка, поведение `const` аналогично поведению `static readonly`, поэтому можно сказать, что константа одна на класс.