# Зачем нужен const, если можно не менять int

Tags: c#, const

Не понимаю, зачем во многих языках используется тип данных const, если можно создать int и не менять его? Прошу объяснить и привести пример.

Comment: С точки зрения семантики вы говорите, что это значение не будет изменяться - и программа проконтролирует это. Самый банальный пример - число "пи", константа, которую можно объявить один раз и быть уверенным, что она не поменяется. Даже в простых программах можно думать, что значение не меняется и где-то его поменять - а в сложных проектах, где множество неочевидных взаимосвязей между модулями и несколькими независимыми командами разработчиков гарантировать неизменяемость проще через const.

Comment: @AK Но а что изменится, если в коде не прописанно изменение этой переменной?

Comment: Const (вернее, его значение) можно использовать прямо в инструкции, тогда как за Int надо слазить в память. Например... Но главное, наверное, в том, что "можно не менять" и "нельзя изменить" - вещи немного разные. Вторая даёт чуть больше гарантий.

Comment: @Akina Опять же, оба варианта дают одинаковою гарантию, если не использовать переменную, компьютер не умеет сам изменять значение переменной, не так ли?

Comment: Представь себе банальную опечатку в имени переменной...

Comment: @Log1c0 Вы исходите из предположения, что все три команды, работающие над проектом и в которой постоянно идёт ротация кадров - они будут разбираться в том, что переменную нельзя трогать. Когда рядом написано const - не нужно никуда лазить по документации и спрашивать коллег, сразу видно - это константа, её нельзя менять. А современный код часто использует рефлексию и не всегда можно в compile time заподозрить, что меняется вот именно та переменная, которую трогать не стоило.

Comment: возможно связанный вопрос: [Выделение памяти под константное свойство в классе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/646660/186999)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

С точки зрения семантики вы говорите, что это значение не будет изменяться - и программа проконтролирует это.

Самый банальный пример - число "пи", константа, которую можно объявить один раз и быть уверенным, что она не поменяется.

Даже в простых программах можно думать, что значение не меняется и где-то его поменять - а в сложных проектах, где множество неочевидных взаимосвязей между модулями и несколькими независимыми командами разработчиков гарантировать неизменяемость проще и удобнее через const.

Тут кстати хорошо напомнить вот о чём. Константы вшиваются сразу в код (при этом достигается копеечная, но всё же выгода) и это в .Net приводит к тому, что если вы меняете константы в одной сборке - то нужно перекомпилировать весь проект. Об этом написано во многих учебниках по шарпу, но случается  забывают и наступают на эти грабли.

С точки зрения компилятора меняется следующее. Если у нас переменная - мы ей выделяем место в стеке/куче под хранение:

```
void Main()
{
    var i = 10;
    i.Dump();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы объявляем константы - то места под хранение не выделяется, во всех местах, где нам нужна константа - подставляется её конкретное значение:

```
void Main()
{
    const int i = 10;
    i.Dump();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь ldc - это load constant, а работа со стеком исчезла - нет этой переменной.

Answer (score 2):

> "можно создать int и не менять его"

Идея, конечно, хорошая, но никаких гарантий не даёт. С таким же успехом можно не надевать шлем при езде на мотоцикле, мотивируя это тем, что "я просто не буду попадать в аварии". К сожалению одного обещания, данного самому себе, как правило недостаточно. Вы можете забыть, что ваша переменная не должна меняться, и изменить её. Хуже того, очень часто код пишется  сразу несколькими разработчиками, которые могут не знать, что переменную `x` менять нельзя, а переменную `y` - можно. Модификатор `const` подскажет это.  Явно объявленный `const` облегчает понимание кода, делает его чуть более декларативным.

Кроме того, константные значения вычисляются на этапе компиляции, и это тоже неплохо. Помимо небольшой, но всё же имеющей место выгоды в плане производительности, очень серьёзным доводом в пользу `const` может оказаться тот факт, что ошибку, связанную с изменением константы вы увидите при компиляции, а ошибку, вызванную изменением переменной, которая должна быть константой, вы увидите только в рантайме, когда она уже (возможно) наделала бед.

Comment: _Кроме того, константные значения вычисляются на этапе компиляции, и это тоже неплохо._ - но накладывает ограничения на возможные значения.

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос как по мне. Вас никто не заставляет объявлять переменную типа `const` потому-что это только для вашего удобства и для общего понимания. Для небольших проектов, как отметил @AK, это не столь заметное применение, но все же удобно. Просто представьте ситуацию где у вас в проекте переменных одного типа штук 200, и вам их иногда но нужно изменять. Но есть пару значений которые изменять в крайне опасно, например для вычислений кредитов там где например проценты для всех сумм одинаковые и их менять ненужно. Было бы нехорошо если бы с вашим кодом работал бы не совсем опытный пользователь, и попытался изменить проценты из 5% например на 0.0001% если не меньше. Представьте какие бы компания потерпела убытки. А в случае с применение keyword `const`, у него бы указалась ошибка связана с изменением значение **КОНСТАНТЫ**, значение которой изменить нельзя.

Подробнее о данной сущности **[тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const)**